# Facebook Graph 2.0 reply page conversations with video attachments

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to reply a page fan using with video attachments or even audio using graph api 2.0?

I have managed to reply users using [this](http://graph.facebook.com/CONVERSATION_ID/messages).

Now I need to reply them with video attachments using PHP. Can you please just point me in the right direction. A rough snippet would do.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/conversation/messages#publish), there is only one parameter available for the conversations endpoint, which is the message. So there is no way to add any attachment.